# How to display one image in loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to display one image in loop. Knowing the path and image-name are okay is this example, how to display one image in loop, and when the image haven't been found, the browser displays the last right image-name until the image-name is found?

```
@{int j=1;}
<img src="" />
<script>
    (function () {
        for (var i = 1; true; i++) {
            @{ string file = "/MonitoringN/../bitmaps/" + j + ".png"; bool a = System.IO.File.Exists(file) == true; }
            var str = "/MonitoringN/../bitmaps/" + i + ".png";
            var b = "@a";
            if (b)
            {
                setInterval(function () { $('img').prop('src', str); }, 1000);
            } else {
                i--;
                @{j--;}
            }
            @{j++;}
        }
    });
</script>
```

Because when I execute this code, I get a blank image, and then I can't see the page is loading.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `@` stuff comes from the Razor engine .. Part of the Microsoft MVC stuff.

Comment: The mvc stuff seems unnecessary. You can do all of this with JavaScript. And the interval always uses str which won't change. And it won't be in its scope. I would suggest making a variable for the counter outside of the function. Then have the interval call a method to make str from that counter do the rest of what it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are trying to do ...

If I understand the question correctly, you have a list of images and you want to try to open them until one of them is found.  If an image is NOT found, you want to skip to the next one.

First -- I'd simply for your question by separating the Razor stuff and the Javascript off into very separate pieces.  In fact, I'm going to skip Razor entirely.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A test</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="http://x.invalid" id="myImage">

<script>
var imgs = [
  "http://x1.invalid/none",
  "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png",
  "http://thedailywtf.com/Resources/Images/Primary/logo.gif"
];


var imageIndex = 0;

function tryNextImage() {
  var img = document.getElementById("myImage");

  img.onerror = function() {
    imageIndex++;
    tryNextImage();
  }

  img.src = imgs[imageIndex];
}

// start the ball rolling
tryNextImage();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```